# MySQL Datetime insert issue. Weird bug?

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-insert

I'm having a problem inserting a record into MySQL version 5.6.15. The problem is the date time.

[image: Table Setup]
The first record inserts without a problem. 
The second complains about the date.

```
INSERT INTO fish_db.fish_tank_temperature VALUES(NULL,'2015-10-04 14:00:27',30);
INSERT INTO fish_db.fish_tank_temperature VALUES(NULL,'2015-10-04 02:00:27',20.5);
**Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2015-10-04 02:00:27' for column 'time_value' at row 1**


select @@sql_mode
**'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'**
```

The schema create script is below for any testing you may try.

It's a very simple schema and table with 3 columns.
An auto-incrementing primary key, time_value and temperature reading

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `fish_db` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `fish_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `fish_db` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fish_db`.`fish_tank_temperature`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fish_db`.`fish_tank_temperature` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fish_db`.`fish_tank_temperature` (
  `idfish_tank_temperature` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time_value` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `temperature` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idfish_tank_temperature`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idfish_tank_temperature_UNIQUE` (`idfish_tank_temperature` ASC),
  INDEX `fish_tank_temperature_idx1` (`time_value` ASC, `temperature` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: Are you from Australia? What timezone do you live?

Comment: Execute `select @@system_time_zone;` and check results.

Comment: @ojovirtual 100% aussie. AUS Eastern Daylight Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that, based on your location (Sydney is what I see in your profile), your system is probably configured to do automatic Daylight Saving Time: on Oct 4th at 2 a.m. it is 3 a.m., so `2015-10-04 02:00:27` is an invalid datetime.

Maybe you should configure your server to use UTC.

Comment: 100% Spot On. Daylight Savings killed the DB. Excellent find.